# Pkg doesn't install dependencies in [deps] of project.toml. Why not?

Tags: package, dependencies, julia

I am using Julia 1.7 and trying to install packages. (In this case, it's the ACE package of github.com/JuliaMolSim/MolSim ). But I notice that when I write `] add ACE`, Pkg does not install the dependencies in project.toml, but it installs ACE itself.

How can I get it to install the dependencies? Thought that was part of the point of having a package manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are talking about [ASE.jl](https://github.com/JuliaMolSim/ASE.jl), not [ACE.jl](https://github.com/ACEsuit/ACE.jl).

There seems to be an issue with JuliaHub. When I try to enter ASE page, it throws 404. The good news is that you can download directly from GitHub:

```
]add https://github.com/JuliaMolSim/ASE.jl
```